# alphabetising table data using arrays / if statements

Tags: php, mysql

I have some data that I'm looping through and alphabetizing using if statements. My code works but the problem is it seems like a very "long way around". I'd like to know if there's another approach that I'm missing that could make this much easier.

Here's my PHP:

```
    // MY QUERY
$query1 = "SELECT `categoryid`, `categoryname` 
            FROM `my_table_category` 
            ORDER BY `my_table_category`.`categoryname` ASC";

$browse = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
$browse_rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($browse)){
    $browse_rows[] = $row;
    }

// HERE MY ARRAYS FOR THE ALPHABET
    $list_a = array(); $list_b = array(); $list_c = array(); 
    $list_d = array(); $list_e = array(); $list_f = array(); 
    $list_g = array(); $list_h = array(); $list_i = array();
// etc...

// HERE IS WHERE I'M GRABBING THE CATEGORY NAMES BY THEIR FIRST LETTER 
// AND ADDING THEM TO AN ARRAY
foreach($browse_rows as $row){
    if($row['categoryname'][0] == 'A'){
        $list_a[] = $row['categoryname'];
    }elseif($row['categoryname'][0] == 'B'){
        $list_b[] = $row['categoryname'];
    }elseif($row['categoryname'][0] == 'C'){
        $list_c[] = $row['categoryname'];
    }elseif($row['categoryname'][0] == 'D'){
        $list_d[] = $row['categoryname'];
    }
} //etc...
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<!-- HERE IS HOW I DISPLAY MY DATA -->
 <div id="topics_a">
            <h2>A</h2>
            <ul class="browse_list">
            <?
            foreach($list_a as $name){
                if ($holdcat <> $name) {
                $holdcat = $name; ?>
                <li><a href="index.php?state="<? echo $template->State."#".$browse_row['categoryid'];?>><? echo $name; ?></a></li> 
            <? }} ?>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="topics_b">
            <h2>B</h2>
            <ul class="browse_list">
            <?
            foreach($list_b as $name){
                if ($holdcat <> $name) {
                $holdcat = $name; ?>
                <li><a href="index.php?state="<? echo $template->State."#".$browse_row2['categoryid'];?>><? echo $name; ?></a></li> 
            <? }} ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
//etc...
```

Updated after the answer:

```
//UPDATED PHP
foreach ($browse_rows as $row) {
$initial = $row['categoryname'][0];
    $lists[$initial][] = $row['categoryname'];
}
//UPDATED HTML
<? foreach ($lists as $letter => $list){ ?>
            <div>
                <h2><? echo $letter;  ?></h2>
                <ul class="browse_list"> 
            <? 
            $list = array_unique($list); 
            foreach ($list as $cat) {
            ?>
                <li><a href="#"><? echo $cat; ?></a></li> 
            <? } ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
            <? } ?>
```

Output:
http://d.pr/i/bt68

Comment: why do you need an array per letter ?

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: do you only utilize one list (e.g. `$list_a`) or all 26?

Comment: I'm using all letters  (e.g. $list_a $list_b etc...)

Comment: @StevenSerrano its a little confusing on why you have multiple loops, multiple arrays, what is the data in your database and what do you want as the final output? how are you using the multiple arrays can you expand on that last code snippit and include your output?

Comment: Don't use separate variables for each letter. Use a multi-dimensional array whose first dimension is the letter key.

Comment: loop the full original list, check for the first letter to change - infinity more efficient than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a multidimensional array, not separate arrays for each letter.

```
$lists = array();
foreach ($browse_list as $row) {
    $initial = $row['categoryname'][0];
    if (!isset($row[$initial])) {
        $lists[$initial] = array();
    }
    $lists[$initial][] = $row['categoryname'];
}
```

Then when you want to display it, sort the array by the keys, then use nested loops:

```
ksort($lists);
foreach ($lists as $list) {
    echo '<ul class="browse_list">';
    $list = array_unique($list); // get rid of duplicates
    foreach ($list as $cat) {
        echo '<li><a href="#">' . $cat . '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million. You and everyone else helped a lot. Still fairly new to php so its much appreciated!